# Regarding BU MID creation

Tags: marketing-cloud

Quick Question. I'm assuming if I would like to have multiple BU. SFMC account Rep can do that. Not me through Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to add another business unit to marketing cloud, yes you need to go through your account executive to MC support to create that BU.

As per my conversation with support team, we need to purchase to get other BU in MC